Generating 3phase SPWM waveforms having control over the frequency from 10Hz to 800Hz
I was referring to web and I got one YouTube video similar to my project but i was not able to get output as shown in the video. I need your help how to rectify the problem. Can someone please verify for me.
Also I need to modify this code such that it has 25kHz switching frequency and controllable output(SPWM pulses) frequency from 10Hz to 800Hz...
Please help me in this. I will be grateful for your help...
Link for YouTube video i referred is
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlNvO4pP0pk&t=12s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19OiazKNChw
Code i got from the video is given bellow, please check:
#include "avr/pgmspace.h"
#include "avr/io.h"

const byte sine256[] PROGMEM = {127,130,133,136,139,143,146,149,152,155,158,161,164,167,170,173,176,178,181,184,187,190,192,195,198,200,203,205,208,210,212,215,217,219,221,223,225,227,229,231,233,234,236,238,239,240,
  242,243,244,245,247,248,249,249,250,251,252,252,253,253,253,254,254,254,254,254,254,254,253,253,253,252,252,251,250,249,249,248,247,245,244,243,242,240,239,238,236,234,233,231,229,227,225,223,
  221,219,217,215,212,210,208,205,203,200,198,195,192,190,187,184,181,178,176,173,170,167,164,161,158,155,152,149,146,143,139,136,133,130,127,124,121,118,115,111,108,105,102,99,96,93,90,87,84,81,78,
  76,73,70,67,64,62,59,56,54,51,49,46,44,42,39,37,35,33,31,29,27,25,23,21,20,18,16,15,14,12,11,10,9,7,6,5,5,4,3,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,14,15,16,18,20,21,23,25,27,29,31,
  33,35,37,39,42,44,46,49,51,54,56,59,62,64,67,70,73,76,78,81,84,87,90,93,96,99,102,105,108,111,115,118,121,124
};

#define cbi(sfr,bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &=~_BV(bit))
#define sbi(sfr,bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) != _BV(bit))

int PWM_OUT_1=11; // PWM output on pin 11
int PWM_OUT_2=10; // PWM output on pin 10
int PWM_OUT_3=9; // PWM output on pin 9

int LED_PIN=13; //LED STATUS ON PIN 13
int TEST_PIN=7; // Scope trigger on pin 7
int POTEN_IN = A0; //Potentiometer on pin 0
int OFFSET_1=85; // Offset for second phase
int OFFSET_2=170; //Offset for third phase
double dfreq;
const double refclk = 31376.6; // measured
const uint64_t twoTo32 = pow(2,32); // compute value at startup and use as constant

// Variables used inside interrupt services are declared as volatile
volatile uint8_t icnt; //var inside interrupt
volatile uint8_t icnt1; //var inside interrupt
volatile uint8_t c4ms; //counter increamented every 4ms
volatile uint32_t phase_accum; //phase accumulator
volatile uint32_t tword_m; // dds tunning word m

//***********************************************************************************

void setup() {
    // put your setup code here, to run once:
    pinMode (LED_PIN, OUTPUT); // sets the digital pin as output 
    Serial.begin(115200); // connect to the serial port 
    Serial.println("DDS Test");

    pinMode (TEST_PIN, OUTPUT); // sets the digital pin as output 
    pinMode (PWM_OUT_1, OUTPUT); // PWM output frequency output 
    pinMode (PWM_OUT_2, OUTPUT); // PWM output frequency output 
    pinMode (PWM_OUT_3, OUTPUT); // PWM output frequency output 

    // Setup the timers
    setup_timerl();
    setup_timer2();

    // disable interrupts to avoid timing distortion 
    cbi (TIMSK0, TOIE0); // disable Timező !!! delay() is now not available 
    sbi (TIMSK2, TOIE2); // enable Timer2 Interrupt 
    dfreq = 1000.0; // initial output frequency 1000.0 Hz 
    tword_m = twoTo32 * dfreq/refclk; //calculate DDSnew tuning word
}

void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    if (c4ms > 250) // timer / wait for a full second
    {
        c4ms > 0;
        dfreq = analogRead (POTEN_IN); // read Poti on analog pin 0 to adjust output frequency from 0..1023 Hz
        cbi (TIMSK2, TOIE2); // disble Timer2 Interrupt
        tword_m = twoTo32 * dfreq/refclk; // calulate DDS new tuning word
        sbi (TIMSK2, TOIE2); // enable Timer2 Interrupt
        Serial.print (dfreq);
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.println(tword_m);
    }
}

//*************
// timerl setup
// set prscaler to 1, PWM mode to phase correct PWM, 16000000/512 = 31.25kHz clock

void setup_timerl (void) {
    // Timerl Clock Prescaler to: 1
    sbi (TCCR1B, CS10);
    cbi (TCCR1B, CS11);
    cbi (TCCR1B, CS12);
    // Timer 0 PWM mode set to Phase Correct PWM
    cbi (TCCR1A, COM1A0); // clear Compare Match
    sbi (TCCR1A, COM1A1);
    cbi (TCCR1A, COM1A0); // clear Compare Match
    sbi (TCCR1A, COM1B1);
    sbi (TCCR1A, WGM10); // Mode 1 Phase Correct PWM
    cbi (TCCR1A, WGM11);
    cbi (TCCR1B, WGM12);
    cbi (TCCR1B, WGM13);
}

//timer2 setup
//set prscaler to 1, PWM mode to phase correct PWM, 16000000/512=31.25kHz clock
void setup_timer2() {
    // Timer2 Clock Prescaler to: 1
    sbi (TCCR2B, CS20); 
    cbi (TCCR2B, CS21);
    cbi (TCCR2B, CS22);

    // Timer2 PWM Mode set to Phase Correct PM
    cbi (TCCR2A, COM2A0); // clear Compare Match
    sbi (TCCR2A, COM2A1);
    sbi (TCCR2A, WGM20); // Mode 1 Phase Correct PWM
    cbi (TCCR2A, WGM21);
    cbi (TCCR2B, WGM22);
}

// Timer2 Interrupt Service at 31.25kHz=32us
// this is timebase REFCLOCK for the DDS generator
// FOUT (M (REFCLK))/ (2 exp 32)
// runtime: 8 microseconds (inclusive push and pop)
ISR (TIMER2_OVF_vect)
{
    sbi (PORTD, TEST_PIN); // Test / set PORTD, TEST_PIN high to observe timing with a oscope
    phase_accum += tword_m; // soft DDS, phase accu with 32 bits 
    icnt = phase_accum >> 24; // use upper 8 bits for phase accu an frequency information OCR2A pgm read byte near (sine256+ icnt); // read value fron ROM sine table and send to PWM DAC OCRIA pgm read_byte_near(sine256+ (uintet) (icnt OFFSET_1)): OCRIB pgm read byte near (sine256+ (uintet) (icnt + OFFSET_2)); if (icnti+125) // increment variable cama every 4 milliseconda
    OCR2A=pgm_read_byte_near(sine256+icnt);//read value from ROM sine table and send to PWM DAC
    OCR1A=pgm_read_byte_near(sine256+(uint8_t)(icnt+OFFSET_1));
    OCR1B=pgm_read_byte_near(sine256+(uint8_t)(icnt+OFFSET_2));

    if(icnt1++ == 125) // increament variable c4ms every 4 milliseconds
    {
        c4ms++; 
        icnt1=0;
    }

    cbi (PORTD, TEST_PIN); // reset PORTD, TEST_PIN
}

